# C# Download file from URL

Tags: c#, file, download

Can anybody tell me how i can download file in my C# program from that URL:
http://www.cryptopro.ru/products/cades/plugin/get_2_0

I try to use WebClient.DownloadFile, but i'm getting only html page instead of file.

Comment: Well, your url points to a html file and that's what you get. Which file do you want to download?

Comment: If you try to open that URL in any browser, downloading begins.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking in Fiddler the request fails if there is not a legitimate U/A string, so:

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36");
wb.DownloadFile("http://www.cryptopro.ru/products/cades/plugin/get_2_0/cadeplugin.exe", "c:\\xxx\\xxx.exe");
```

Comment: I added above header but it didn't work for me. I am trying to download a  encrypted text and an exe file.

Answer (score 4):

I belive this would do the trick.

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.DownloadFile("http://www.cryptopro.ru/products/cades/plugin/get_2_0/cadeplugin.exe","file.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the download status or use credentials in order to make the request, I'll suggest this solution:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri ur = new Uri("http://remoteserver.do/images/img.jpg");
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
client.DownloadDataCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, @"C:\path\newImage.jpg");
```

And her it is the implementation of the callbacks:

```
void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);
}

void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
}
```

Comment: Should be DownloadFileCompleted instead of DownloadDataCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WebClient.DownloadData`

You would get response in the form of `byte[]` then you can do whatever you want with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a server would not let you download files with scripts/code. to take care of this you need to set user agent header to fool the server that the request is coming from browser. using the following code, it works. Tested ok

```
 var webClient=new WebClient();
 webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] =
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";
 webClient.DownloadFile("the url","path to downloaded file");
```

this will work as you expect, and you can download file.