# Download csv file from URL return html page c#

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a simple code to download a file from URL and it worked until few months ago.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
    client.DownloadFile(someUrl, "Companies.csv");
}
```

If I enter the URL manually the file will download: [CSV file URL](https://data.gov.il/dataset/246d949c-a253-4811-8a11-41a137d3d613/resource/f004176c-b85f-4542-8901-7b3176f9a054/download/f004176c-b85f-4542-8901-7b3176f9a054.csv)

Why wouldn't it download via c# code?

I saw the question in [C# Download file from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718348/c-sharp-download-file-from-url) but didn't seem to find my answer there.

Comment: Why it has +1? this code works ... obviously the remote service doesn't return CSV but html ... prolly to avoid such downloads(data scraping)

Comment: Is there a way to get the info from that file with download?

Comment: yes, by solving javascript from this HTML ... so you need javascript interpreter ... or by using browser automation

Comment: It seems the target URL doesn't serve the CSV, or at least not directly. It seems to return an HTML page with an empty <body>. The CSV file is generated via JS scripts loaded via the <head> section. Initially I was unable to event download the file because my browser (Brave) blocked the scripts... As such, you might want to rethink your approach, as I don't think `WebClient` will suffice.